# Converting markup to jQuery object results in array instead of DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get a page via AJAX, filter the result and add it after an existing DOM element:

```
$.get(url, null, function(response)
{
    $response = $(response);
    $response.find('#content > article').after('#content > header')
})
```

`response` is a full HTML document with doctype, `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`

I would expect that I can use all of the normal jQuery functions on `$response` but it looks like it is just a jQuery-wrapped array - or something equally useless in my case.

I set up a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gvytutvL/1/) of what I am trying to do (sans AJAX).

How do I turn a string representation of a full HTML page into a usable jQuery object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) command only searches in descendant elements.  Change your command to this:

```
$("<div/>").append(markup).find('#insertme').insertAfter('#first')
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gvytutvL/3/

Comment: Thanks! I've done similar things in the past. I didnt realize this was what was occurring here.

Comment: You can also use $.xml and then you don't have to append first.

Comment: @Michael what is `$.xml`?

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ, my mistake, there is no $.xml method, but I meant you can force 'xml' as the data type, see an answer below.

Comment: Of course. You answered so quickly, SO wouldn't let me accept the answer yet. Here you go...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could try setting the content type as XML, I have found that lets you parse it as an HTML fragment before you append:

```
function success(xml_fragment) {

    $response = $(xml_fragment);
    $response.find('#content > article').after('#content > header')
}

$.get(url, null, success, 'xml');
```